# Не отправляться HTTP запрос через Curl

Tags: php, curl

Добрый вечер,

Проблема в том что когда в адресную строку пишешь вот такой адрес:

```
http://apps.lsim.az/sendsmsjm/restful/quicksms/send?login=onetaxi&msisdn=994552925049&text=Hello+World&sender=One+Taksi&key=key
```

Вот curl код:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://apps.lsim.az/sendsmsjm/restful/quicksms/send?login='.$login."&msisdn=".$msisdn."&text=".$text."&sender=".$sender."&key=".$key;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Много вариантов перепробовал. Ничего не помогает.Что тут не правильно?

Comment: Какое сообщение об ошибке? Если вывести `$url` при помощи `echo`, какой будет результат?

Comment: Не нужно постить свои ключи, удалите этот комментарий. Достаточно было сказать, что поведение ожидаемое или хотя бы вымарать собственно ключ.

Comment: это апи-сервис? отдает ответ по GET параметрам?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант.

```
<?php


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/tester.phtml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// используйте что то типа этого
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// Получаем ответ
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// проверка ответа
if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }

?>
```

Comment: Это для POST запросов.

Comment: curl_exec не возвращает `ОК`

Comment: @УзеирЗейналзаде закомментируйте эту строку
**curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);**